# items not within the <ul></ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

1. I create a menu with a javascript object and jquery. I have certain items that needs to be in the `<ul></ul>` but instead they're beneath it.

   http://jsfiddle.net/MWBt6/
2. I have 'Index' for example. In there I want to append a list of items.

   I know the category id is 0 and the item id is 2, i stored those things in the data attribute.

Now how can I append a ul to that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how `append` works. You need to create the elements on their own. Here:

```
var loadPath = "resources/books/book1/";

var menu = {
    data: [{
        name: "the book",
        id: 0,
        items: [{
            name: "Introduction",
            id: 0,
            target: "inleiding.html"
        }, {
            name: "Content",
            id: 1
        }, {
            name: "Index",
            id: 2
        }]
    }, {
        name: "my stuff",
        id: 1,
        items: [{
            name: "Notes",
            id: 0
        }, {
            name: "Marks",
            id: 1
        }]
    }, {
        name: "other",
        id: 2,
        items: [{
            name: "Search",
            id: 0
        }, {
            name: "Continue Reading",
            id: 1
        }]
    }]
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var $menu = $('#menu');

    for(var i = 0; i < menu.data.length; i++) {
        var categorie = menu.data[i];
        var categorieName = categorie.name;
        var categorieId = categorie.id;
        var items = categorie.items;

        console.log("categorieName: " + categorieName);

        var list = $('<ul>');

        for(var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
            var itemId = items[j].id;
            list.append($('<li>').attr('data-itemId', itemId).text(items[j].name));
        }

        $menu.append(
            $('<li>').attr('data-categorieId', categorieId).append(categorieName, list)
        );
    }
});​
```

[Here's the updated jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/MWBt6/5/)

Comment: can you explain the `.append(categorieName, list)` why the first parameter. I looked at the jquery documentation but it's not really helping.

Comment: @clankill3r: It's just a simpler way of saying "append them both": `.append(categorieName).append(list)`

Comment: but categorieName is a string, `var categorieName = categorie.name;` so why append that?

Comment: @clankill3r: It's the name of the category. See what the jsFiddle looks like without appending the name.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to append as if the DOM is a text editor. You can't append the beginning of an element with it's opening tag, then later close that element with an append of a closing tag. Only full valid elements can be inserted into the DOM.

Instead, build an html string, then only make one append after the string is completed. This method is far more efficient than doing multiple appends also

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MWBt6/3/